# How to make a simple list of primitive fields of object with Serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm creating Rest API with Django Rest Framework for my clients and I'm confused while creating a structure of it. I want a structure like this with `DRF Serializers`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alan",
        "toys": [
            "Robocop",
            "Ninja",
            "Megalodon"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
        "toys": [
            "Avatar",
            "Donatello Turtle",
            "Super Mario"
        ]
    },
]
```

My serializers look like:

```
class GoodBoyToysSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()


class GoodBoysSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    toys = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_toys(self, good_boy):
        queryset = Toy.objects.filter(good_boy=good_boy)
        serializer = GoodBoyToysSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

It returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alan",
        "toys": [
            { "name": "Robocop" },
            { "name": "Ninja" },
            { "name": "Megalodon" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
        "toys": [
            { "name": "Avatar" },
            { "name": "Donatello" },
            { "name": "Super Mario" },
        ]
    },
]
```

What can I do? I tried using ListSerializer and etc. But, unfortunately, all of these are useless.

`Python 3`, `DRF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning a list in your serializer:

```py
class GoodBoysSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    toys = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_toys(self, good_boy):
        queryset = Toy.objects.filter(good_boy=good_boy)
        return queryset.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with several solutions. One of them is using `SlugRelatedField`.

According to documentation:

> `SlugRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using a field on the target.

For my case, It would look like:

```
class GoodBoysSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    toys = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        many=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = GoodBoy
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'toys']
```

where `slug_field` is **required**. And it will return the same result

You can also pass a `queryset` as a parameter for related field.